# upload_preset not found Cloudbinary Widget using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, api

I am having some issues trying to include the cloudbinary widget to my site... [here is the docs](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#signed_uploads)

I am trying to do signed uploads, so we developed a backend route that generates the signature.

So my code is this:

```
$('.cloudBinaryWidget_init').cloudinary_upload_widget({
        cloud_name: 'demo',
        upload_preset: 'a5vxnzbp',
        api_key: key,
        upload_signature: generateSignature,
        cropping: 'server',
        folder: 'temp',
        theme: 'white',
        inline_container: '#cloudBinaryWidget_container',
        button_class: 'cloudBinaryWidget_trigger',
        stylesheet : '#cloudinary-navbar{background:#f4f4f4;box-shadow:none!important}#cloudinary-navbar .source.active{border-bottom:6px solid #2dc8d2}.button.capture_camera,.button.select_file.select_single,.button.upload_url{background:linear-gradient(60deg,#2dc8d2 0,#22e5c9 100%)!important}#cloudinary-widget .button,#cloudinary-widget .button.small_button{background:linear-gradient(60deg,#2dc8d2 0,#22e5c9 100%)}'
    },
    function(error, result) {
        console.log(error, result)
    });

var generateSignature = function(callback, params_to_sign){
    $.ajax({
        url     : urlCreateCloudBinaryWidgetSignature,
        type    : "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        data    : { data: params_to_sign},
        complete: function() {console.log("complete")},
        success : function(signature, textStatus, xhr) { callback(signature); },
        error   : function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr, status, error); }
    });
}
```

And when I have to uplaod the image, I am receiving this error:
[image]

So it is strange because signed uploads doesn't require uplad_preset... At least it says in the docuentation mentioned above.

Any help please?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Just starting our proof of concept with Cloudinary and we're encountering the same problem.

Comment: @YeeHaw1234 Finally I fixed it. I had to gestionate it through their platform. it was not a JS error

Comment: "gestionate" -> "generate"